# Point of intersection of parametric curves

Tags: calculus

Consider the two curves given in parametric form by
$a(t) = (t^2 − t, t^2 + t)$ and $b(t) = (t + t^2, t − t^2)$ for $t ∈ \Bbb{R}.$
e the solutions wrong? Thanks to the answers below. This part now makes sense.

ii. Find the angle between the two curves at each point of intersection?

The $2$ points are $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$

I did $$\theta=cos^{-1}\frac{(0,0)\bullet(0,0)}{\sqrt{0^2+0^2}+\sqrt{0^2+0^2}}$$ but I get $0$ in the denominator.

And for case two,$$\theta=cos^{-1}\frac{(2,0)\bullet(2,0)}{\sqrt{2^2+0^2}+\sqrt{2^2+0^2}}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$which  happens to be wrong. Please help...

Comment: How did you get the formulas for the angle? If I understand the question correctly you want the angles between the curves. Which means angles between their tanget vectors, yet you seem to be plugging in the points instead of tangent vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the angle between two curves, you find the angle between the *direction vectors* (or *derivative vectors* or *tangent vectors*), not between the points themselves.

Your first step is to find the derivatives of those curves, then to find the tangent vectors at those intersection points. Then find the angles between *those* vectors.